# using __gte in django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, user-input, django-queryset

I have a search fn where am doing this.

Template

```
<input class="range-slider-3" type="text" name="years">
```

View

```
yrs = request.POST.get('years')
users = User.objects.filter(years_of_exp__gte=yrs)
```

This `queryset` brings all the users with years_of_exp value in their profile regardless of the number.
If I put 100 or 40 or 44 or 78 in the search box I get all the users even if their `years_of_exp` is 2 in the db.

Any reason why this is happening? Maybe am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting yrs back as a string and comparing the value to an integer, which will result in comparisons like this:

```
'2' >= 100
```

which unfortunately (for you) is True in python 2.x.

You need to cast yrs to an int:

```
yrs = int(request.POST.get('years'))
```

Comment: Great. Also the model field was `CharField` instead of `IntegerField`. Working perfectly now, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you put 100 in the box, you are searching users with years_of_exp greater than 100. If you look at the fields in the User database rows, do you have any number greater than 100 ? What's the type of years_of_exp ? Which django version do you use ?

For everything to work, you have to make sure everything is ok:

- Make sure your form method is POST, and that `request.POST.get('years')` is not empty
- You might want to cast `request.POST.get('years')` to an int first, even though your RDBMS should be able to understand that your string is actually used as an integer.

Comment: I don't think `years_of_exp` is a year. It's probably a number of years.

Comment: well, 100 was an example. Any value I search behaves the same. its really wierd

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as soon as I wrote this.